# PHP Initialize class with a var is ok but with a constant it fail. Why?

Tags: php, oop

I am currently building a MVC and I ran into a little problem (I got the solution already), but :

This fail because `Fatal error: Call to undefined method Controller_Home::DMVC_DEF_CTRL_FUNCTION()` ..

```
if(method_exists($Controller, DMVC_DEF_CTRL_FUNCTION)){
    $Controller->DMVC_DEF_CTRL_FUNCTION($SecondRoute);
} else {
    // 404
    die;
}
```

This work :

```
$MethodName = DMVC_DEF_CTRL_FUNCTION;
if(method_exists($Controller, $MethodName)){
    $Controller->$MethodName($SecondRoute);
} else {
    // 404
    die;
}
```

`DMVC_DEF_CTRL_FUNCTION` is a constant.

Can someone explain this to me why a constant wouldn't work ? I also tryed for fun with the [constant](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.constant.php) function but no success.

I think PHP think it is a function. How can I tell PHP that the constant `DMVC_DEF_CTRL_FUNCTION` ain't a function ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use a constants value as method name, you could utilize the curly expression syntax:

```
 $Controller->{CONSTANT_NAME}($SecondRoute);
```

As otherwise the identifier would only ever be interpreted as method name.

Answer (score 2):

In your current code the interpreter believes that you are calling a method on the object with the name DMVC_DEF_CTRL_FUNCTION. Since DMVC_DEF_CTRL_FUNCTION is a constant and not a varaible, php is taking the name instead of the actual value it is holding.

You can force php to take the value instead in the following way:

```
 $controller->{DMVC_DEF_CTRL_FUNCTION}( "Blah" );
```

**Update**

When using a class constant instead of a global constants, the following will work as well:

```
 $controller->{self::DMVC_DEF_CTRL_FUNCTION}( "Blah" );
```

Comment: Yes, this is working and this is what I wanted to do in the first place. I didn't know I could use `{}` to force as a value. Also, it has no impact on the generated required time versus a variable.

Comment: It has a small memory advantage as you do not have to initialise yet another variable to memory and can work with the constant that has already been created.

Answer (score 1):

PHP knows that a variable holds data, that's the purpose of a variable.  This is why you can use variable variables and execute a function like you're trying to do, by evaluating the variable  How would it know that you meant to use this as a constant instead of just the actual name of the function?

You could use the following to execute the same purpose:

```
if(method_exists($Controller, DMVC_DEF_CTRL_FUNCTION)){
    call_user_func(array($Controller, DMVC_DEF_CTRL_FUNCTION),$SecondRoute);
} else {
    // 404
    die;
}
```

Comment: I like the way you use your `call_user_func`. I will run test to see if it make a diffrence versus a variable. That's what I wanted to know if we could make it possible with a constant and... yes it is. Thanks

Comment: Ok after the test I just did, your way take ~0.000010 and my way with variable take ~0.000008 so it variable instead of call_user_func is 12.5% faster.

Comment: Yes, using call_user_func and call_user_func_array have overhead since you are calling a function to call a function.  I wasn't aware you wanted a high-performance solution, in which case your way would indeed give you performance gains (if .000002 will make or break your application due to recursion or a low latency requirement).

Comment: High performance is the goal. This will be a critique application and in the work sheet it is written : Fast as possible even little optimisation. So I try to do my best ! :P The bracket solution is equal to the variable in term of speed.

Answer (score 0):

For this line:

```
if(method_exists($Controller, DMVC_DEF_CTRL_FUNCTION)){
```

have you done a `define('DMVC_DEF_CTRL_FUNCTION', 'some value')` previously? If not, you're checking for an undefined constant, which will effectly become

```
if (method_exists($Controller, NULL)){
```

`method_exists()` requires you pass in the name of the method as a STRING. Since you've not quoted the `DMVC...` part, it's going in as a constant, which means it must have been defined previously.

edit:

```
$x = 'hello';
define('x', 'goodbye');

$obj->x();  // this is NOT going to call hello() **OR** goodbye()
```

Comment: Yes, it is defined before of corse... methodt exists is working the way it is suppose with the constant. It is when I call the class.

Comment: Your edit : For `$x` you'll need `$obj->$x();` and $obj->hello() will be called. But for the constant x that what I was trying to do but this wasn't working. That what I wanted to know why. Thanks

Comment: Using an undefined constant castes to a string so if it were undefined the line would effectively become if (method_exists($Controller, 'DMVC_DEF_CTRL_FUNCTION')){

Answer (score 0):

PHP doesn't know that you aren't calling a function DMVC_DEF_CTRL_FUNCTION as in

```
function DMVC_DEF_CTRL_FUNCTION()
{
    // some function
}
```

Crashspeeder is right. You can use call_user_func, but why not just tell PHP to replace the constant before it tries to call the function:

```
$Controller->{DMVC_DEF_CTRL_FUNCTION}($SecondRoute);
```

Add brackets around the constant.